# Feynman-Bethe Critical Mass Formula

Tags: nuclear-physics

According to the historical lore of the making of the atomic bomb at Los Alamos, Richard Feynman and Hans Bethe supposedly worked out a formula for the critical mass for the core of the A-bomb. Is it true that this formula they developed is still classified and if so, why would this be classified given the fact so many countries have the bomb now and there are thousands of physicists who are familiar with the equations of the bomb's basic physics?

Comment: Try this: http://nuclearweaponarchive.org/Nwfaq/Nfaq4-1.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) The basic formula was worked out by Rudi Peierls, and (openly!) published in 1939, see Peierls, R.: Critical conditions in neutron multiplication. Proc Cambridge Philos Soc 35, 610–615 (1939).

2) The Peierls paper does not have a numerical estimate in it, because he lacked numerical values for the number of secondary neutrons and the mean free path in $^{235}U$ (and he did not know about $Pu$). The first numerical value is in the British Maud report, which you can read [here](http://www.atomicarchive.com/Docs/Begin/MAUD.shtml)

3) The result was improved by many people, including Robert Serber, Hans Bethe, and (probably) Feynman. A standard reference is Robert Serber's "Los Alamos Primer", which you can buy at Amazon.

4) The standard history of these events is Richard Rhodes "The making of the atomic bomb".

Comment: Thanks all for the responses, I was hoping there would be documentation showing how Feynman and Bethe worked it out, it's always interesting to see how great minds solve these kinds of problems.

Comment: @WilliamHird: "*There are two types of genius. Ordinary geniuses do great things, but they leave you room to believe that you could do the same if only you worked hard enough. Then there are magicians, and you can have no idea how they do it. Feynman was a magician.*"
—Hans Bethe